# How do I get the .getJSON() jquery data out of the response?

Tags: jquery, json

```
function saveCallerReference(callerReference){
    $.getJSON('/index.php?r=site/AJAXsaveCallerReference', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });

}
```

Given the above, the line "return data;" never gets returned, when the function(data){} exits, where does that return go? I want my outer scope function, saveCallerReference, to return the value from the getJSON(). console.log() is printing correctly so I am getting the data.

Comment: take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you expect it to be returned to? the function being called is **anonymous**...

You need to understand that `$.getJSON` happens **asyncronously** so the normal top-down flow does not apply, you need to do whatever you need to trigger whatever you want to do with `data` **inside the callback**...

```
$.getJSON('/index.php?r=site/AJAXsaveCallerReference', function(data) {
    functionThatDoesWhatYouWant(data);
});
```